# MacBook randomly missing characters when typing

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I'm using the keyboard built into my MacBook. For some reason when I am typing, my MacBook sometimes doesn't show a character I type. However when I type another letter it appears. So my MacBook is registering all of the keystrokes, but for some reason it's randomly not showing certain characters until another one is typed.

Comment: Have you tried connecting an external keyboard to see if it's a hardware (builtin keyboard) or software (MacOS itself) issue?

Does it happen in every app?

Comment: Do you have the notorious Butterfly Keyboard (i.e. a MacBook built between 2016 and 2019)?

Comment: @X_841 I guess so, Macbook Pro 2019

Comment: @AshZade Yes it happens in every app. I have not yet tried plugging in an external keyboard.